# Openpyxl and Hidden/Unhidden Excel Worksheets

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have the following code that reads data from a tab-delimited text file and then writes it to a specified worksheet within an existing Excel workbook. The variables "workbook", "write_sheet", and "text_file" are input by the user

```
tab_reader = csv.reader(text_file, delimiter='\t')
xls_book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=workbook)
sheet_names = xls_book.get_sheet_names()
xls_sheet = xls_book.get_sheet_by_name(write_sheet)
for row_index, row in enumerate(tab_reader):
        number = 0
        col_number = first_col
        while number < num_cols:
                cell_tmp = xls_sheet.cell(row = row_index, column = col_number)
                cell_tmp.value = row[number]
                number += 1
                col_number += 1
xls_book.save(workbook)
```

However when I run this code on a preexisting "workbook" in which "worksheet" is a hidden tab, the output unhides the tab. I think the reason is because openpyxl is not modifying the file but creating a new file entirely. Is there an easy way to tell python to check if the worksheet is hidden and then output a hidden or unhidden sheet based on whether or not the condition is satisfied?

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We currently don't support hiding worksheets in openpyxl so this is just ignored when reading the file and, therefore, lost when saving it. I don't think it should be too hard to add it. Please submit a feature request on Bitbucket.

**[UPDATE]**

The feature is now available:

```
ws.sheet_state = 'hidden'
```

Or actually `xls_sheet.sheet_state = 'hidden'` in your particular case.

Comment: I just checked with a recent copy and this still appears to be the case. Maybe no issue was ever submitted.

Comment: Actually, is been available for a while https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issue/309/openpyxl-and-hidden-unhidden-excel
`ws.sheet_state = 'hidden'`

Comment: My checks confirm that `sheet_state` changes persist into a newly-saved copy, but when Excel loads the workbook containing that sheet it nevertheless displays the sheet whose `sheet_state` was set to `"hidden"`. Should I raise an issue?

Comment: The code looks like it should be preserving the value but I can't see a dedicated test (it's sort of difficult to write a simple one). Please submit an issue if you think it's not working. PR with tests welcome, too! ;-)

Comment: @CharlieClark, maybe you can update the answer instead of leaving it hidden in the comments.