# Hide unhide sheets from python

Tags: python, excel, hide, openpyxl

I´m trying to hide and unhide some sheets in python.

I´m using openpyxl, but can´t find how to do it.

Any idea, or another library to do this process?

Answer (score 2):

```
ws.sheet_state = 'hidden'
```

and I'm guessing for this one :

```
ws.sheet_state = 'visible'
```

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23170772/4628637

Comment: Thanks i will check the link