# Pandas to_excel with sheets being hidden, or efficiently hiding excel tabs?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

Creating and saving df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Attribute1': ['A', 'B'], 'Attribute2': ['X', 'Y']})
filename = 'test.xlsx'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter') 
with writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='2nd tab')
```

I'd like to add something like `hidden=True` to a sheet condition but [pandas doesn't seem to support this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

We can [do this manually with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157643/openpyxl-and-hidden-unhidden-excel-worksheets/23170772#23170772), but it's prohibitively slow for large files:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename)
wb["df"].sheet_state='hidden'
wb.save(filename)
```

Clearly the best solution is to not use Excel, but that's the requirement. What's a practical way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-hide ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get a handle to the XlsxWriter worksheet object to hide it. Like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Attribute1': ['A', 'B'],
                   'Attribute2': ['X', 'Y']})

filename = 'test.xlsx'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter')

with writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='2nd tab')

    # Get a handle to the worksheet.
    worksheet = writer.sheets['2nd tab']
    worksheet.hide()
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to hide the first worksheet you need to do a bit of extra work since Excel doesn't allow you to hide the "active" worksheet, which is generally the first worksheet. In that case you also need to "activate" another worksheet. Like this:

```py
with writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='2nd tab')

    worksheet = writer.sheets['df']
    worksheet.hide()

    worksheet = writer.sheets['2nd tab']
    worksheet.activate()
```

Output:

[image]

For more details see the [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)

Also note, the `datetime_format` parameter in your example is incorrect. That is a property of the writer class and not the `to_excel()` method. I left it out of the example above.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I didn't know `with writer` could be used like that. And thank you for pointing out the issue with `datetime_format`. I've removed it in interest of avoiding confusion for others.