# Reading only visible sheets using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an existing code which uses pandas to read an excel workbook.
It reads all the sheets including the hidden ones however, I want to read only the visible ones. Tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581768/how-to-read-only-visible-sheets-from-excel-using-pandas), but it didn't help:

The below are the snippets tried out.

```
xlFile = '/path/file_name.xlsx'
xl = pd.ExcelFile(xlFile)

list_of_visible_sheets = []
sheets = xl.book.sheets()
for sheet in sheets:
    if sheet.visibility == 0:
        list_of_visible_sheets.append(sheets) 
print(list_of_visible_sheets)
```

and

```
list_of_visible_sheets = []
sheets = xl.sheet_names
for sheet in sheets:
    if sheet.visibility == 0:
        list_of_visible_sheets.append(sheets) 
print(list_of_visible_sheets)
```

How can I get the visible sheets alone?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157643/openpyxl-and-hidden-unhidden-excel-worksheets  It seems that you can use `openpyxl` (which is likely the engine that pandas is using for .xlsx). Open the workbook and iterate through the sheets checking for `ws.sheet_state = 'hidden'`. Pass the list of visible sheets as a parameter to `ExcelFile()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code with `openpyxl`. It roughly does what the pandas `read_excel()` function does:

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

filename = 'TestFile.xlsx'
#Number of rows to skip in each sheet    
nSkip = 1

dfs = { ws.title : pd.DataFrame(list(ws.values)[nSkip:])
        for ws in openpyxl.load_workbook(filename,read_only=True).worksheets 
        if ws.sheet_state != 'hidden'  }

print(dfs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It works well. Just that `read_excel()` had an option to mention the number of rows to skip, which was very easy to use.  (Took some time to simplify the code to my understanding. :) Posting it [here](https://gist.github.com/pyarisinghk/b873b2f277e28da463f455497b05699e). Thank you once again for introducing me to [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

Comment: @pyari I amended the code to allow for skipping rows

Comment: `@DS_London - That helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the `sheetname` argument to `pandas.read_excel`
If there are not too many sheets, you can create the desired list manually, or use the recipe from *that* answer and lambdas.

Comment: Lambda looks like a good idea. I am sure he doesn't want to make a visible list manualy.